# ストリーミングサーバ、RED5について

Tags: flash

ストリーミングサーバ、RED5について質問があります。
久しぶりにインストールする必要がありダウンロードサイトを見たのですが
下記のサイト全て見ることが出来なくなっております。
本家公式サイト： http://www.red5.org/
本家開発サイト： http://trac.red5.org/
ソースコード： http://red5.googlecode.com/
日本Red5ユーザー会： http://www.red5.gr.jp/

サービスを終了したのでしょうか？
状況がわかりましたら教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://red5.googlecode.com/ にアクセスすると次のように書かれています。

> Project "red5" has moved to another location on the Internet.
>   ...
>   View the project at: https://github.com/Red5

おそらく、[GoogleCodeが2016年に終了する](http://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/articles/1503/13/news055.html)ことを受けての対応だと思います。

そして https://github.com/Red5 には様々なプロジェクトが並んでいますが、上の方に  http://red5.github.io/ というリンクが置かれています。まだコンテンツはほとんどないようですが・・・。

日本語ユーザー会は確かに情報がないですね・・・。

Comment: 有難うございました。
新しいLINUXとの相性も怪しいので今回は見合わせることを考えます